# Como trocar o valor de duas variáveis em Java?

Tags: java, variáveis

É possível criar uma função em Java que troque o valor de duas variáveis, sem precisar declarar uma variável temporária?

Por exemplo:

```
int a = 8, b = 3;
if(a > b) {
    // algo aqui, sem declarar uma variável "tmp"
}
// agora a deve valer 3 e b deve valer 8
```

Em outras linguagens, como C++ e C#, seria possível passar os parâmetros por referência, mas Java não tem esse recurso.

Answer (score 12):

Como pode ser visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2393934) é impossível fazer um método `swap`, da forma tradicional (passando os valores por referência), em Java, já que [Java só aceita passagem por valor](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

No entanto, são propostas várias soluções. Como uma das respostas propostas, é possível utilizar uma [função auxiliar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20600020). No entanto, você pode criar um método de swap para listas ou vetores, como é proposto na solução original.

Caso você não queira criar um método, é possível realizar um `XOR`:

```
a = a^b;
b = b^a;
a = a^b;
```

baseado [nessa propriedade](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_XOR_Swap).

Comment: "é impossível fazer um método `swap` em Java" É bom esclarecer: impossível no sentido do método - **como efeito colateral** - fazer com que o valor de `a` vá para o endereço/ponteiro/referência de `b` e vice-versa. Pois a única maneira de se atribuir uma referência simples em Java é através de um operador no próprio contexto do método onde ela é declarada.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, bem  notado, no caso é impossível fazer um `swap` da forma tradicional (utilizando os valores passados como referência). Vou editar a resposta para ela ficar mais adequada.

Answer (score 7):

É possível usar uma função auxiliar como esta:

```
int returnFirst(int x, int y) {
    return x;
}
int a = 8, b = 3;
a = returnFirst(b, b = a); // Leia como a = b; b = a;
System.out.println("a: " + a + ", b: " + b); // prints a: 3, b: 8
```

Usando a função returnFirst, temos uma solução que cumpre quase todos os requisitos:

1. A troca de valores é feita em apenas um statement;
2. Não é necessário declarar uma variável temporária (não polui o código do chamador);
3. Não aloca objetos temporários;
4. Com alguns overloads, sendo um deles com um generic `<T>`, funciona para qualquer tipo;
5. A implementação da auxiliar é trivial;
6. Não usa truques que só funcionam números inteiros (como XOR).

A especificação da linguagem Java ([Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, seção 15.12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2)) garante que o valor de b é avaliado e passado antes de ser sobrescrito pela atribuição b = a no segundo argumento, ao contrário de outras linguagens (pelo que me lembro, C e C++ não são nada amigáveis e não garantem ordem nenhuma de avaliação dos argumentos, só garantem que eles todos serão avaliados antes da função começar a executar, obviamente).

Se você escolher um nome curto como `r1`, fica bem fácil de ler

```
a = r1(b, b = a);
```

como se fosse

```
a = b; b = a;
```

(embora na verdade `b = a` execute primeiro)

Answer (score 6):

Se suas variáveis são inteiras, você pode usar [o truque do XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm):

```
int a = 8, b = 3;
if(a > b) {
    a = a ^ b;
    b = a ^ b;
    a = a ^ b;
}
// agora a deve valer 3 e b deve valer 8
```

Comment: Hehe, pra ser sincero estou aproveitando que o site é novo para responder minha própria pergunta com um truque que eu achei mais legal que o XOR :-)

Comment: @marcus interessante mesmo, +1

Comment: Sem problema, não pretendo fazer isso com freqüência. A resposta é de minha própria autoria, então está OK.

Comment: Eu tinha lido as regras e vi que podia, mas parece que o pessoal não gosta mesmo de "autorrespostas", haha :-)

Comment: Aliás, para ficar completo: link para a minha resposta original em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363186/is-it-possible-to-write-swap-method-in-java/16826296#16826296

Answer (score 6):

O jeito mais fácil é somar as duas variáveis e depois subtrair pelo valor inicial da outra. Dessa forma:

```
int a= 8, b = 3;
a =  a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Comment: Essa é uma boa alternativa ao XOR, quando restrita a números inteiros (e quando o comportamento padrão em caso de *overflow* é "ignorar" - [como é o caso de Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3001836/520779))

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Troca {
    int a;
    int b;
    int aux;

    public int trocaA(){
       this.aux = this.b;
    return this.aux;
   }
    public int trocaB(){
       this.b = this.a;
    return this.a;
    }
    public void mostrar(){
        System.out.println("\n|-----------------|");
        System.out.println("| 1º Valor era: "+this.a+" |\n| Agora vale: "+trocaA()+"   |");
        System.out.println("|-----------------|");
        System.out.println("| 2º Valor era: "+this.b+" |\n| Agora vale: "+trocaB()+"   |");
        System.out.println("|-----------------|");

}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Troca tr = new Troca();
        Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1º Valor: ");
        tr.a = ent.nextInt();
        System.out.println("2º Valor: ");
        tr.b = ent.nextInt();

        tr.mostrar();

    }
}
```