# Como trocar o valor entre duas variaveis sem utilizar variavel auxiliar?

Tags: c, ruby, variáveis

Aprendi a programar em C, mas recentemente tenho estudado RUBY.

Ruby permite que troquemos o valor entre duas variaveis facilmente e sem utilizar uma variavel auxiliar, assim:

`a, b = b, a`

Sem utilizar uma variavel auxiliar, como posso fazer isso em C?

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como trocar o valor de duas variáveis em Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4033/como-trocar-o-valor-de-duas-variaveis-em-java) Salvo a linguagem, a prática é a mesma.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Não me parece a mesma pergunta. A pergunta indicada usa variável intermediária para fazer o swap. E a sua resposta com XOR dada na pergunta indicada só se aplica para números.

Comment: Porquê? O uso de variável auxiliar é o método reconhecido por 100% dos programadores de C para trocar o valor entre duas variáveis. Além disso, muito provavelmente, o executável será optimizado e não vai usar variável auxiliar.

Comment: Concordo com o @FelipeAvelar

Comment: Não concordo com o fechamento, Java e C são duas linguagens diferentes, e há espaço para respostas específicas para cada uma, veja o exemplo estendido que usa macros.

Comment: Não acho que seja duplicata desse post de java, porque cmo dito pelo @Bacco, a minha questão pergunta se em C teria como fazer algo igual exemplifiquei em RUBY, sem o uso de variavel auxiliar. São parecidas sim, mas não sao iguais.

Comment: @Bacco, mas é explicado que não é possível fazer o swap em java, justamente porque ele não aceita passagem por referência, o que não acontece em C...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar ou seja, não é duplicata mesmo :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se estiver utilizando apenas tipos integrais (`int`, `long`, `unsigned char`, ...) pode usar um truque com o XOR, assim:

```
x ^= y;
y ^= x;
x ^= y;
```

Não há nenhuma limitação com relação à magnitude do valor. Sim, funciona com `INT_MAX`. Experimente escolher um par de número e fazer esse calculo na mão para entender como funciona.

Se você quiser implementar uma macro que funcione para qualquer tipo, temos algumas possibilidades. A forma mais simples é a seguinte:

```
#define SWAP(x, y) do {   \
      typeof(x) temp = x; \
      x = y;              \
      t = temp;           \
    } while (0)
```

Essa funciona para o caso geral, mas tem alguns problemas. Primeiro, ela depende de uma extensão do GCC, o `typeof`. Isso não está presente em todos os compiladores. Segundo que você pode passar tipos diferentes para x e y, e isso não deveria ser permitido. E por último, se uma das variáveis se chamar `temp`, você terá a macro falhando silenciosamente.

Repare que se usar a opção da macro, tecnicamente você nunca vai realmente ver a variável adicional. Sendo assim é como se ela não existisse, uma abstração.

Para fazer uma versão mais arrojada tomei por base uma feita por [@adamk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3982430):

```
#define SWAP(x, y) do { \ 
      unsigned char temp##x##y[sizeof(x) == sizeof(y) ? sizeof(x) : -1]; \
      memcpy(temp##x##y, &y, sizeof(x)); \
      memcpy(&y, &x,         sizeof(x)); \
      memcpy(&x, temp##x##y, sizeof(x)); \
    } while(0)
```

Infelizmente o highlight do está errado ali. Ignore isso.

O primeiro passo é declarar uma variável cujo nome é `temp##x##y`. Isso contatena `temp`, `x` e `y`, garantindo que o identificador nunca é igual a nenhum dos dois. Em seguida uma array é declarada com `sizeof(x)` bytes. Mas note que se `sizeof(x) != sizeof(y)`, o tamanho será `-1` e a compilação vai falhar. Por último a copia é feita usando `memcpy`. Pode parecer ineficiente mas na realidade não é. Se o tamanho for pequeno o compilador vai remover isso e fazer a cópia diretamente. Se o tamanho for grande (for uma enorme struct), `memcpy` é a forma mais rápida de fazer isso de qualquer forma. Repare que `typeof` não é usado.

Answer (score 12):

Uma das formas mais simples e rápidas de o fazeres é recurso a operações matemáticas.

Assumindo que `x = 50` e `y = 70` com 3 operações:

```
x= x + y 
y= x - y 
x= x - y
```

Explicação detalhada

```
• x= x + y | x= 70 + 50 , basicamente x=120

• y= x - y | y = 120 - 70 , ficamos com y=50

• x= x - y | x= 120 - 50 , finalmente x=70.
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: E o que é que acontece se x = INT_MAX e y = INT_MAX?

Comment: Claro que é um método pouco ortodoxo , mas é o mais simples visto ele não querer uma 3ª variavel..  Mas um "convert.ToInt32" ou algo go género poderia ajudar

Comment: O que quero dizer não se prende com o tipo, mas sim com o facto de que ao usar a solução proposta, se x e y forem INT_MAX, vai causar um overflow do int, causando undefined behaviour.

Comment: Eu sei e tens toda a razão, mas suponho que não será o caso ou ele não estaria a pedir esta solução porque o uso de uma 3ª variavel é o mais acertado em qualquer ocasião. Caso seja integers ou algo do género , a solução esta correta caso contrário não estou a ver solução sem uso de uma 3ª. Cumpz

Comment: Correcto, mas neste caso acho que será preferível indicar na resposta as limitações do código, nomeadamente a possibilidade de overflows et al.

Answer (score -3):

```
a = (a * b);
b = a / b;
a = a /b ;
```